# PHP - Execute PHP Script On Page Load?

Tags: php, sql, count, counter

I want PHP script which counts how many times an item has been bought, increasing the counter by one every time the PHP script (of the purchase) has been executed, and showing it in the page database.

Let's say, when the user is redirected back to the site via Paypal they load the page thankyou.php which on load, increases the database value (of the counter) in a table by one.

I couldn't find any examples so I'm hoping you kind guys here could help me out.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Query the database, get current total.

Add one.

Store new value.

Plenty of tutorial available for this.

Comment: Updated the post* Sorry if that wasn't clear at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php is server side language that is executed on sever side before the page loads. in your case you have to make ajax call to trigger the php code.

```
Update: mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET id = id + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Comment: Any code examples I could take a look at?

Comment: Such a simple task can be done on the page itself.

AJAX seems totally overkill.

Comment: Actually there is no need for ajax... he can use something like a tracking pixel like: `<img src="/counter.php" />`

Comment: No need for AJAX at all... this is a pure php job, or server side for that matter

Comment: well my answer fit his description before he updated his question.

Comment: It's not really even an answer, it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to increment the value in PHP, you can do it in your query directly in your query:

```
UPDATE hits_log SET hits = hits+1 WHERE page = *somthing*
```

This can be executed using php's [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) library, or similar.